# Slashes and backslashes uniform compatibility in PHP for UNIX and Windows

Tags: php, windows, unix, cakephp-1.3, backslash

In my PHP code, I have this:

```
$directory = WWWROOT."img\\".$component."\\ProductTemplate\\";
```

When I execute my program on a Windows server, I get this:

```
C:\Users\jaimemontoya\[path]\app\webroot\img\medium_thumb\ProductTemplate\
```

When I execute my program on a UNIX server, I get this:

```
/home/jaimemon/public_html/[path]/app/webroot/img\medium_thumb\ProductTemplate\
```

My program is working correctly on the Windows server, but it is not working properly on the UNIX server.  Should I first detect the operating system and after that, use the corresponding code? Is there a built-in PHP function to achieve this type of compatibility? Any ideas will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: PHP is supposed to fix all this automatically I thought. Simple rule though is use Unix `/` even on windows as PHP on windows will fix the slashes

Comment: You always have the [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) constant, but as @RiggsFolly pointed out, use `/` when working with paths instead and let PHP handle it for you.

Comment: @RiggsFolly You are saying that I use in my case `$directory = WWWROOT."img/".$component."/ProductTemplate/";`, correct?

Comment: Yes that's what I was suggesting

Comment: @RiggsFolly When I use `$directory = WWWROOT."img/".$component."/ProductTemplate/";`, I get the problem fixed on UNIX but it breaks my system on Windows because for Windows I get this: `C:\Users\jaimemontoya\[path]\app\webroot\img/medium_thumb/ProductTemplate/`. That means that I get the opposite problem. It works on UNIX and it does not work on Windows.

Comment: This is wierd, I have developed on Windows and Implemented on Linux for year now and never had this issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly I thought it may be a PHP built-in function to deal with this kind of problem, since I am sure it is a common situation programmers have to deal with. I develop this program on Windows and deploy it on a UNIX server. Maybe there is a way to detect the operating system and based on that, use `/` or `\` accordingly.

Comment: Windows should be able to handle `C:\Users\jaimemontoya\[path]\app\webroot\img/medium_thumb/ProductTemplate/` even though there are \ and /. So maybe so windows setting?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following somewhere in my code:

```
/*
 * Use the DS to separate the directories in other defines
 */
if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}
```

I guess that `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is a constant built-in for CakePHP. I am not sure. But it works. I used this:

```
$directory = WWWROOT."img".DS.$component.DS."ProductTemplate".DS;
```

Now it works on both UNIX and Windows. For Windows I get this:

```
C:\Users\jaimemontoya\[path]\app\webroot\img\medium_thumb\ProductTemplate\
```

For UNIX I get this:

```
/home/jaimemon/public_html/[path]/app/webroot/img/medium_thumb/ProductTemplate/
```